# Symbol for "stick" combinatorial principle

Tags: set-theory

In [Sticks and clubs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007297000304) there is a special symbol for the combinatorial principle "stick". Could you please help me to find out what is the command in Latex to generate this symbol?

Comment: Try detexify: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: For the person who downvoted, could you share with me why you did it? Maybe with your feedback I can improve my question. On the other hand, detexify doesn't seem to have the symbol in question in its database, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this seems to be a question about TeX (which has it's own stackexchange), not math.

Comment: @Peluso: I didn't downvote this.

Comment: If you didn't downvote, that's ok, my comment is for the person who did downvote. My apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is not really an on-topic question here.  It might be on-topic at [tex.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper is on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9804153), and for most arXiv papers, the TeX source is publicly available. Click on "Other formats" in the "Access Paper" box, and select "Download Source".

Looking in the preamble, we find the following code that the authors used to create the "stick" symbol.

```
\newcommand{\stickT}{%
\setbox255=\hbox{\raise1ex\hbox{$\hspace{0.2pt}\,\bullet\,$}}
\mathord{\rlap{\hbox to\wd255{\hss\hbox{$|$}\hss}}
\box255}
}
\newcommand{\stickS}{%
\setbox255=\hbox{\raise0.6ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\bullet$}}
\mathord{\rlap{\hbox to\wd255{\hss\hbox{$\scriptstyle|$}\hss}}
\box255}
}
\newcommand{\stick}{{\mathchoice{\stickT}{\stickT}{\stickS}{\stickS}}}
```

Comment: The approach isn't bad, and the components are reasonable , but I'd stay away from `box255`, because that's the box in which TeX compiles the page to be shipped out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create
`\newcommand{\dotabovebar}{\overset{\bigcirc}{{|}}} \dotabovebar`
Or,`\newcommand{\dotabovebar}{\overset{\bullet}{{|}}} \dotabovebar`

$\newcommand{\dotabovebar}{\overset{\bigcirc}{{|}}} \dotabovebar$ Or,  $\newcommand{\dotabovebar}{\overset{\bullet}{{|}}} \dotabovebar$

Comment: Maybe as a temporary fix it will work to define a new command, but I'm under the impression that there must be a specific command because I don't notice that there is a space between the "dot" and the "vertical line" in the original symbol. Thank you for your answer.